# Why does my code for running not work with the else function, but work without it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Image of it with the else function added (not working) And an image of it working

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TRxh.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn7ys.png

Answer (score 0):

the `Input.GetKeyDown` function in unity checks if you pressed a key for a frame so it returns true during the frame the user starts pressing down the key, check here the documentation :
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html 
If you want a function that returns true during all the frames where the player is pressing the key use `Input.GetKey`, doc here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html